# MySQL not using index with selective INT key

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

I have created the table measurements as listed below.
This table is written to periodically and will rapidly grow to contain millions of rows after a few days.
On read: I only need the precise time of the measurement and its value (unix_epoch and value).

To improve performance, I have added column date_from_epoch which is the day extracted out of unix_epoch (the measurement precise time) in this format: yyyymmdd. It should have a good selectivity (after multiple days of measurements have been written to the table) and I am using it as a key for an index. I am hoping to scan only the days for which I want the measurements on read, and not all the days present in the table (example: after 10 days, if 1,000,000 are added each day, I am hoping to scan only 1,000,000 rows if I need data contained within one day, not 10,000,000).

I have also:

- used innoDB for the engine
- partitioned the table by hash into 10 files to help with I/O
- made sure the type used in my query is the same as the column type (or did I get this verification wrong?).

Question:
I have made a test after measurements have trickled in the measurement table for 2 days.
Using EXPLAIN, I see my read query does not use the index. Why is the query not using the index?

Table is created with:

```
CREATE TABLE measurements(
date_from_epoch INT UNSIGNED,
unix_epoch INT UNSIGNED,
application_name varchar(255),
environment varchar(255),
metric_name varchar(255),
host_name varchar(1024),
value FLOAT(38,3)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
PARTITION BY HASH(unix_epoch)
PARTITIONS 10;

CREATE TRIGGER write_epoch_day 
BEFORE INSERT ON measurements
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.date_from_epoch = FROM_UNIXTIME(NEW.unix_epoch, '%Y%m%d');

ALTER TABLE measurements ADD INDEX (date_from_epoch);
```

The query is:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM measurements
WHERE date_from_epoch >= 20150615 AND date_from_epoch <= 20150615
AND unix_epoch >= 1434423478 AND unix_epoch <= 1434430678
AND BINARY application_name = 'all'
AND BINARY environment = 'prod'
AND BINARY metric_name = 'Internet availability'
AND (BINARY host_name = 'kitkat' )
ORDER BY unix_epoch ASC;
```

Explain gives:

```
id  select_type         table           type        possible_keys       key         key_len         ref         rows       Extra     
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   SIMPLE              measurements    ALL         date_from_epoch                                             118011     Using where; Using filesort
```

Thanks for reading and head-scratching!

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to use **`FORCE INDEX` in MYSQL**

Refer [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-hints.html) for better understanding.

Comment: The link which I have shared, also mentions other ways to use the index. You can check that

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sashi!

I have modified the query to

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM measurements FORCE INDEX (date_from_epoch)
WHERE date_from_epoch >= 20150615 AND date_from_epoch <= 20150615
AND unix_epoch >= 1434423478 AND unix_epoch <= 1434430678
AND BINARY application_name = 'all'
AND BINARY environment = 'prod'
AND BINARY metric_name = 'Internet availability'
AND BINARY host_name = 'kitkat'
ORDER BY unix_epoch ASC;
```

Explain says still "Using where; Using file sort" but the number of rows scanned is now down to 67,906 vs the 118,011 initially scanned (Which is great).

Although the number of rows for date_from_epoch = 20150615 is 113,182. I am now wondering why the number of rows scanned is not 113,182 (not that I want it to go up, but I would like to understand what mysql did to even further optimize the execution).

Answer (score 0):

A lot of things need fixing:

- Don't use `PARTITION BY HASH`; it does not help.
- Since you have a range across the partition key, it must touch all partitions.  See `EXPLAIN PARTITIONS SELECT ...`.
- Don't bother with the extra epoch_from_date and Trigger; just do comparisons on unix_epoch.  (See the manual on the conversion routines needed.)
- Don't use `BINARY`.  Instead, specify the columns as `COLLATION utf8_bin`.  Performance will be much better.
- Normalize (or turn into an ENUM) these fields: application_name, environment, metric_name, host_name.  What you have is unnecessarily bulky for millions of rows.  (I am assuming there are only a few distinct values for those fields.)  The space savings will make the `SELECT` run much faster.
- `FLOAT(38, 3)` has an extra (unnecessary?) rounding.  Simply use `FLOAT`.
- (After making the above changes) `INDEX(application_name, environment, metric_name, host_name, unix_epoch)` would be quite helpful, at least for that one query.  And it will be significantly better than the `INDEX` you are asking about.